# React Navigation share params between tabs in tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having some trouble with a tab navigator. I have 3 tabs in this tab navigator.

I have a component which, on press, navigates to one of these three routes depending on a condition, and pass some params.

However, when I switch to another tab, the params I passed should be shared with this tab.

For example I have this:

```js
tabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  TabNumber1,
  TabNumber2,
  TabNumber3
);
```

From the other component I do something like this:

```js
navigation.navigate('TabNumber1', myParams);
```

It takes me there and it works fine, but when I go to TabNumber2 the navigation is handled by the Tab Navigator so I have no way of passing the params of the current route.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This collection is passed to the path that the user navigates, in which case it becomes a tap path and is not one of the screens in the path. To import a params that passes from one of these screens to Tab Navigator

```js
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam('setParamNameKey')
```

discussion related to this: [What should happen when passing params to a navigator route?](https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/43)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest storing this data inside [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) or with the [Context Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

**AsyncStorage**

```
const KEY = 'some-specific-key';

export const getDataFromStorage = async () => {
  const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY);
  if (data) return JSON.parse(data);
  return null;
};
```

**Context**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({
  userId: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

function Auth() {
  const { login, userId } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return !userId && <Button onClick={() => login('12345')}>Log in<Button>;
}

function App() {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  const login = (userId) => {
    setUserId(userId);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUserId(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userId, login, logout }}>
        // Your code
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Both options work fine in your use case. However I'd suggest using the Context Api. It may be a bit complex to wrap your head around, but when you understand it you can simply share global state over your App. And AsyncStorage is removed from React Native, so it is only accessible via the [React native community](https://github.com/react-native-community/).